# Force an inheritor to initialise a field of the base from its CTOR (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to enforce an inheritor of an abstract class to initialize one of the fields in the base.

I can't do this via a constructor in the base because the type of the field requires a reference back to the object creating it. (I suppose I could provide a parameterless ctor for the field type. But I feel that would just be shifting the problem, and it should be immutable anyway).

Perhaps someone can suggest how to do it, or maybe make it so I don't need to do it at all?

This is pretty much what I'm doing:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    // Would like to force setting in CTOR
    protected BaseImplementation _implementation;  
    protected BaseImplementation Implementation 
    { get { return _implementation; } }

    public void DoSomething()
    {    
        Implementation.DoSomething();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseImplementation
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class MyObject : Base
{
    // Note its Nested
    public class MyImplementation : BaseImplementation
    {
        private MyObject _myObject;

        public MyImplementation(MyObject myObject)
        {
            this._myObject = myObject;
        }

        public override void DoSomething()
        {
            // Does something
        }
        public virtual void SomethingElse()
        {
            // Does something else 
        }
    }

    new public MyImplementation Implementation
    {
        get { return (MyImplementation) _implementation; }
    }

    public void SomethingElse()
    {
        Implementation.SomethingElse();
    }
}
```

To give a little context, I have a number of classes which inherit from the base. They, intern have multiple ways which they can manipulate their state. This has been the best solution I have come up with for handling that.

### Edit

I forgot to mention that I'm not using an Abstract property because it means I cant use `new public MyImplementation Implementation {...`. I don't want to have to cast Implementation to MyImplementation whenever I use functionality specific to the derived class *(thus using `new` in the first place)* or create multiple fields containing the same object.

Comment: is it me or does forcing an inheritor of an abstract class to initialize one of the fields in the base, seem wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't add a field to the base class. Simply make it an `abstract` property. Derived classes will have to override it and return their own value.

```
protected abstract BaseImplementation Implementation { get; }
```

Alternatively, you can make  the base class constructor accept an argument of type `BaseImplementation` and have the derived class initialize it:

```
public abstract class Base { 
    protected Base(BaseImplementation implementation) {
        _implementation = implementation; 
    }

    private BaseImplementation _implementation;  
    protected BaseImplementation Implementation { get { return _implementation; } }
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public Derived() : base(new MyImplementation()) { }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1. I would also consider using an interface (e.g. IImplementation) instead of an abstract class, it will give you greater freedom to implement it in different ways.

Comment: @Courtney: You are sacrificing design correctness for syntactic beauty, which is not a good thing IMO. This is not a big deal. Simply declare a new property with a different name in the derived class: `public MyImplementation MyImplementation`.

Comment: @Courtney: The alternative method might suit your case better.

Comment: Alas ': base(new MyImplementation())' isn't valid when MyImplementation requires a reference to the object creating it ('this' isn't available). However I figured in bed I can create an abstract property called DefaultImplementation, and use that from the Base CTOR to set the field.

Comment: `this` is unavailable in that context, of course, but you can call static methods and decide the output based on the arguments passed to the constructor. That's enough most of the time.